# Finding conditional from integral relating two marginals

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a marginal probability mass distribution $P_X(x)$ and a density function $f_Y(y)$. The probability mass function is given by the following integral:

$$
P_X(x) = \int_y g(x,y) f_Y(y) dy,
$$

for some non-negative function $g(x,y)$. Does this mean that $g(x,y)$ is a conditional distribution function $P_{X|Y}(x | y)$, such that $\sum_X P_{X|Y}(x | y) = 1$? In other words, if a integral is a probability mass function and the integrand decomposes into a density and some other function, is the other function automatically a proper conditional probability mass function?

Comment: Yes, it has to be.

Comment: Thanks! Do you perhaps have some reasoning or reference as to why?

Comment: If $P_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(x, y)dy$, where $P_X$ is a pmf, and $h$ is non-negative over its domain, then $h$ has to be the mixed joint pdf of the discrete random variable $X$ and another continuous random variable $Y$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Mixed_case